# Flex: Refreshing view when flex application is visible

Tags: apache-flex, refresh

Flex application is contained in one of the rows of a html table, and that row is hidden as per one use case.

Flex application is refreshed when visibility of the row is changed to visible.

This results in lose of data that is already entered in the flex application. Is there any way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to maintain state after a page refresh, you can store session data via the [Flex Shared Object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

Basically, you cannot STOP this behavior flat-out, but you can implement functionality to make it stop.